# Cypress web table column check with loop

Tags: cypress

[image]

Hi All , i am new in cypress. from the image , i have two dropdown properties, in the 'security Information ' there are option to add a security into freeze. if i adding more securities it will shown in a table view. currently there are two security added in to freeze(72135,72149). and in the Rebalancing Grid section , i have another table which contains more details with securityiD. now i have to check from the above two security ids are exist in the below tables or not and Start$ value is correct or not. i can pull the securityID s from the 1st tables and stored in a variable, but how can i check those with the second tables.

i have declared a variable securities = [72135,72149] manually for testing, now i have to find securities from the variable in the second table , and if i get it , than i find the value of securityID from the another column in the second table. i am stuck in to getting the value for this particular securities from the 'Start$' columns. its showing always 0.
i didn't find where i did mistake.

here the code:

```
var securities = [72135,72149]
        cy.get(' :nth-child(3) > div > span:visible').then(($el,index,$list) => {  //securityID column from the table

            Cypress._.each(securities, (tag) => {

                if (expect($el).to.contain(tag))
                {

                    cy.get(' :nth-child(5) > div > span').then(function(amount)  // Start $ column  from the table
                    {   
                    const amount = Number(mPrice.val())
                    expect(amount).to.equal(50.00)
                    })

                 }
          })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

[From cypress doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parent.html#No-Args):

```
<ul class='main-nav'>
  <li>Overview</li>
  <li>Getting started
    <ul class='sub-nav'>
      <li>Install</li>
      <li class='active'>Build</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

// yields .sub-nav
cy.get('li').parent('.sub-nav')
```

Similarly you need to select the parent element of the cell containing the `securities` value:

```
[72135, 72149].forEach((value) => {
    cy.get('<reference to table container>').contains(value)
    .parent('<parent>')
    .siblings().eq(3).find('span').then(($el) => {
        const amount = Number($el.text())
        assert.equal(amount, 50);
    });
});
```

`<reference to table container>` is required so that cy can select the value from within the table and not anywhere else in the page.

If `<parent>` selector cannot be uniquely selected you can try 'old-fashioned' way of chaining `.parent().parent() ...n times` to reach the table column